# Admin-on-Rest Data Grids not loading pagination with Typescript/React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, datagrid, admin-on-rest

I am putting together an admin-on-rest dashboard, and I have the resource talking to a back-end MongoDB database, the appropriate data shows up on my front end, and everything looks fine. There's just one problem: pagination isn't working. I made 100 mock data records and they all load on the first page, even though the pagination indicator at the bottom of the page correctly shows 10 pages for the 10 records/page that A-o-R defaults to.

Here is a gist of the entire `App.tsx` that initiates the dashboard (~50 lines, so shunted off to a link): https://gist.github.com/tmesser/39627e3170cdb5c6481526bbe8b08a33

To explain a bit, the state stuff is not at all wired up right now and should not be doing anything, but the lines of code exist and could ostensibly be causing a problem, so I include the entire thing so as to not accidentally hide something.

Also for completion, here is the `UserList.tsx` code referenced:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { List, Datagrid, TextField, EmailField, DateField } from 'admin-on-rest';

const UserList = (props) => (
  <List {...props} title="All Contacts" perPage={10} sort={{field:"created_at", order:"DESC"}}>
      <Datagrid>
          <TextField label="Id" source="id" />
          <TextField label="First Name" source="first_name" />
          <TextField label="Last Name" source="last_name" />
          <TextField label="IP Address" source="ip_address"/>
          <EmailField source="email" />
          <DateField label="Created On" source="created_at"/>
      </Datagrid>
  </List>
);

export default UserList;
```

Comment: The problem probably lies in the `restClient`, which either doesn't receive or doesn't properly decode content range. See the first note in https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#simple-rest